# Checkout Submodules in another Project in Azure DevOps Repository

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-submodules

I'm trying to checkout a submodule from another project in azure devops.

```
steps:

- checkout: self
  submodules: true
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
```

Checking out another repository in the same project works.

**GOAL**

Add as submodule REPOSITORY A in REPOSITORY B.

[image: Projects]

However i get the error:

```
Cloning into 'E:/build/Agent5/_work/16/s/.azuredevops'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: clone of 'https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECTA/_git/REPOSITORYA' into submodule path 'E:/build/Agent5/_work/16/s/.azuredevops' failed
```

How can i achieve this using YAML in Azure DevOps Repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When adding a submodule i found out that the url in the .gitmodules were not correct.

```
path = .azuredevops
url = https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECTA/_git/REPOSITORYA
```

Should be:

```
path = .azuredevops
url = https://ORGANIZATION@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECTA/_git/REPOSITORYA
```

Comment: Hey @Bruno where to find .gitmodules and update path I am not using submodules: true

Comment: Hey @NaveenKumar, the submodules only appear after you add a submodule. If you have already added it it should be in a hidden file in the root of your repository, try also to select in Windows folder the option to show hidden files if it does not appear.

Comment: Interestingly, the first one does work locally, but only the second one also on the Azure servers. :-/

Comment: @BrunoMartinsPro I realize it's been years since you posted this answer, but I'd love to know more about how you discovered this.

Answer (score 10):

There was on option "Limit job authorization" that was checked on by default, in the Project Settings (bottom of the the left menu).

Turning it *off* solved the issue.

[image: Project setting pane, option that solved issue]

And FYI I just had this to be added in the yaml, under `steps:`:

```
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
```

Answer (score 3):

I had turned off the "Limit job authorization scope" settings on an Organizational level, but was still being blocked. It turns out you need to turn them off for each individual Project as well. It does NOT get inherited.

Comment: I appreciate your username :P

Answer (score 2):

i think this means pipeline doesnt have access to repo B in project B. but I dont think docs say it is possible across projects (although I do notice it says same Azure Devops Organization in couple of places, instead of same Project), but it might be, you can follow thit link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#authenticated-submodules

In case that doesnt work you'd need to use a scripted approach get a PAT token and use that for the checkout:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#alternative-to-using-the-checkout-submodules-option

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your repos are in the same **organization**, and there is no policy or security blocking checking out repos between project, then you could achieve on two ways

## 1. Using `git submodule update`

In this method we are using `System.AccessToken` to authenticate against `https` repositories specified in `.gitmodules` file. **BTW. all submodules MUST be on HTTPS!**

```yaml
pool :
    vmImage : "ubuntu-latest"

stages :
  - stage : Build
    jobs :
      - job : Build
        steps :
          - script: |
              git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" \
                  submodule update --init --recursive
            displayName: Fetch Submodules
```

## 2. Using `repositories` task

Below pipeline will checkout repositories and mount them at the path locations. Path `/s` is important because, it will checkout repo into code working directory, and if **Project A** file system contains `libs/repo-one/` and `libs/RepoTwo/` paths, then source code of **Project B** will be mounted there.

```yaml
pool :
  vmImage : "ubuntu-latest"

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo-one
    name: Project B/repo-one
    type: git
 
  - repository: RepoTwo
    name: Project B/Repo Two
    type: git
  
stages :
  - stage : Build
    jobs :
      - job : Build
        steps :
          # Project A
          - checkout: self
            submodules: false
            path: "s/"
          # Project B
          - checkout: repo-one
            path: "s/libs/repo-one/"
          - checkout: RepoTwo
            path: "s/libs/RepoTwo/"
          
          - script: |
              ls -la .
              ls -la libs/repo-one
              ls -la libs/RepoTwo
            displayName: Debug File System
```